# Installshield 2015 Professional, visual studio 2013 and new version of a product not replacing files

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, installshield-2015

I'm stuck with a problem with IS 2015 pro. I build the setup inside Visual Studio 2013.
When i release a new version of my product, i do it in a new branch in TFS. 
Then, i change the file version of my binaries, change the setup version and change the package code.

With this configuration, the version is replaced "Program and feature" in windows BUT the binaries are not overwrited...

I tested this configuration : Change the file version of my binaries, change the setup version and change the product code.

With this configuration, the binaries are overwrited BUT the version is NOT replaced "Program and feature" in windows.

How can i simply reinstall all files and replace the "Program and Feature" in windows ? I just have 1 component in the setup and everything can be replaced...

Thanks

Whiletrue

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify how you are installing each version of these packages. The first case sounds like a minor upgrade, and that requires special command line handling if you are using the .msi file directly. The second case sounds like a major upgrade (and doesn't require special command lines), but will only be such if you configured it in the Upgrades view.

Comment: You may try a Major Upgrade by changing Package Code, Product Version, and Product Code. Check: http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield22helplib/helplibrary/MajorMinorSmall.htm

Comment: If I change Product version, Package code and Product code to force a Major Update, the system doen't recognize the new version as an upgrade...